# Problems with Numpy and CGI

Tags: python, numpy, cgi, scientific-computing

I decided to create a project which performs computation on a given input of the user.

I installed Python 2.7.2 and Numpy 1.6.1. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit with apache2 installed. My .cgi files are placed in /usr/lib/cgi-bin. 
The first script math.cgi looks as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from numpy import *
from numpy.linalg import *
b = array([9,8])
a = array([[3,1], [1,2]])
x = solve(a,b)
print x
```

I can run it by typing python math.cgi in /usr/lib/cgi-bin and get the correct output. I used chmod +x math.cgi. But when I take a look at http://127.0.1.1/cgi-bin/math.cgi I get an Internal Server Error 500.

Does anyone have an idea what I need to fix, such that http://127.0.1.1/cgi-bin/math.cgi will also give the correct output?

Answer (score 1):

You have to print the header first, such as described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#introduction)

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"     # HTML is following
print                               # blank line, end of headers
print x # your output
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n" did it.

Comment: @macydanim you should mark this as the answer to your question, since it worked for you.